# Have shading begin at 0 but not scale

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm having some trouble getting the chart to scale and shade correctly.

I want the **shading** begin at 0. In other words for positive values, it should only shade above the X axis; for negative values only below the X axis.

However I want the **scale** to be relative to the actual values.

If I set `scaleBeginAtZero` to false (default) then this is what the chart looks like. Notice that it starts shading from the bottom, -10, so it's misleading and appears that all of the values are positive.

[image]

If I set `scaleBeginAtZero` to true, then it correctly shades positive and negative, but the lowest value is 0 and anything below 0 gets cut off (and the tooltips don't appear)

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve (roughly photoshopped from the first chart). The scale is the same as the first chart, but the shading starts at the 0 axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by hooking into the `draw` function of the first point (because you are basically closing off the path drawn by the line to do the fill) and using the y = 0 points to close off the path, like so.

```
Chart.types.Line.extend({
    name: "LineAlt",
    initialize: function (data) {
        Chart.types.Line.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        var scale = this.scale;
        var firstDataset = this.datasets[0];
        var firstPoint = firstDataset.points[0];
        var min = (scale.min > 0 ? scale.min : (scale.max > 0 ? 0 : scale.max));

        originalDraw = firstPoint.draw;
        firstPoint.draw = function () {
            ctx.lineTo(firstDataset.points[firstDataset.points.length - 1].x, scale.calculateY(min));
            ctx.lineTo(firstDataset.points[0].x, scale.calculateY(min));
            ctx.fillStyle = firstDataset.fillColor;
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();

            return originalDraw.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

and you also have to turn off the datasetFill option (since we are doing it on our own)

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).LineAlt(data, {
    datasetFill: false
});
```

If you also want to move the x axis labels, the cleanest way to do it would be to turn off the current labels and just draw your own using the `xLabels` collection

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/dnpo61tu/

Comment: Wow, thank you! For some reason it would only draw a gray line for me, until I hovered over a tooltip, then it would redraw the chart with the shading in the correct blue color I'd chosen. `myChart.update();` after initiliazing the chart fixed that

Comment: Ah, you probably had animation set to false.

Comment: ah, yes I do. Thanks again

Comment: I made one revision because otherwise if the graph was entirely positive, the fill color would bleed under the graph, covering the labels. Seems to work well but wanted to tell you in case you saw a problem with it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33124444/revisions I'm guessing there'd be a similar problem if all values were negative

Comment: Thanks! You were right about the negative values too - it was easy to figure out what to update based on your edit. Cheers!

Comment: Anybody know how to get this to work with angular charts, which is an implementation of Char.js? I tried using this method in the config section of my module and had no luck.